# how to enable SSL email in django?

Tags: django, email

I have in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.myserver.pl'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@mail.myserver.pl'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

But my server require SSL and I get AuthenticationError exception. How to enable SSL support in Django?

Comment: @rantanplan: I suggest you write that in as an answer.

Comment: @MattH I can't take rep for such a simple question!

Comment: This does not work, server, login and pass is proper

Comment: "This does not work" means nothing to me.

Comment: @rantanplan: Your problem. I use EmailMultiAlternatives to send message, on old server it work but new email server require secure authentication. django-smtp-ssl also generate error on send (more than 1 value to unpack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:
  EMAIL_USE_SSL = True